# Composite Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K_1$, $K_2$ be two finite extensions of $F$ of degree $m$, $n$ respectively. It is well known that if $(m,n)=1$, then $[K_1K_2:F]=[K_1:F][K_2:F]$. Is the converse true? i.e if $[K_1K_2:F]=[K_1:F][K_2:F]$, then can we conclude that $[K_1:F]$ and $[K_2:F]$ are relatively prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $K_1=F(\sqrt2)$, $K_2=F(\sqrt3)$. We have $K_1K_2=F(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$, so $[K_1K_2:F]=4=[K_1:F][K_2:F]$, but $\gcd(2,2)=2>1$.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy and I should have thought of that.